# Timeout time ignored when Sikuli/Java program ran from command line

Tags: java, command-line, sikuli

I have written a short Sikuli script utilizing Java in Eclipse. Originally I created a swing GUI to begin execution, and this fires off the Sikuli script as intended (Waits for images, finds them, clicks them. Timeouts after 90 seconds if not found). Now I'm trying to get it to run from command line while taking in an input file as an argument. The command I'm using is below:

```
java -jar SikuliProject.jar intputFile.xlsx
```

I'm seeing my print statements in the commandline, so I know it's running the script, yet it's returning an image found error without waiting the expected 90 seconds :
[error] Region.exists: seems that imagefile could not be found on disk

Is there any reason why the program ignores wait times and can't seem to find images when run this way via commandline opposed to executing from a GUI / IDE?

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: We could use some Java code here. Anyway, if you're getting an error there's the possibility that the timeout block of code is being skiped due to the error reported. Is the image loading isolated by a try catch block?

Comment: The timeout is included in the assert(same line the errors come from) so I don't believe it's being skipped. Code provided below:

`if (screen.exists(image.similar(similarity),timeout) != null) {
screen.wait(1.0);
screen.click(image);
}`

Although, You might be onto something here with the images. I think I might need to move them to a hardcoded location, because right now they're being called in an image folder located in the java project directory:

`Pattern image = new Pattern("img/image.png");`

Comment: The image location was the issue. Thanks for the help aldux!